# C++ template specifying type in the parameter

Tags: c++, templates

In a C++ template when you specify the type in the parameter (example below) does this imply that the type has to be an int or this a hint?

```
template<typename T=int>
    class Square_
    {
    }
```

Comment: It's the default value, in case you don't give one.

Comment: It work just like with default arguments: If no type is provided it defaults to `int`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You specify a *default type*. This means you can omit the type when instantiating the template, in which case this default type is chosen. But when you manually specify a type, this one has precedence. Example:

```
Square_<double> sq1; // explicitly given
Square_<> sq2; // uses default: int
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a *default*, same as for function arguments. So, you can use `Square_<>` to mean the same as `Square_<int>`, when you don't want to choose a different type to the default.

Eg, this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

void function(int i = 42)
{
    std::cout << "function(" << i << ")\n";
}

template <typename T = int>
void function_template()
{
    std::cout << "function_template<" << typeid(T).name() << ">\n";
}

int main() {
    function();
    function(56);
    function_template<>();
    function_template<double>();
}
```

gives me the output

```
function(42)
function(56)
function_template<i>
function_template<d>
```

(the printed names of the types int and double may be different on your system)

Answer (score 0):

It means if you use empty <>, it is equivqlent to use 
See the example below.

```
template<typename T=int>
class Square_
{
    public:
    Square_()
    {
        if (std::is_same<T, int>::value)
        {
            std::cout<<"I am an int"<<std::endl;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout<<"I am not an int"<<std::endl;
        }
    }
};

int main() {
    Square_<> s1;
    Square_<int> s2;
    Square_<double> s2; 
    // your code goes here
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

> I am an int
>
> I am an int
>
> I am not an int